# XPath selecting between comments multiple times

Tags: html, xpath, html-agility-pack

We need to read node between HTML comments:

```
<html>
<!-- comment 1 -->
 <div>some text</div>
 <div><p>Some more elements</p></div>
<!-- end content -->

<!-- comment 2 -->
 <div>some text</div>
 <div><p>Some more elements</p>
 <!-- end content -->
 </div>
</html>
```

I tried using the below XPath:

```
//*[preceding-sibling::comment()[contains(., 'comment 1')]][following-sibling::comment()[contains(., 'end content')]]
```

It works fine for first comment i.e. comment 1 but not working for second comment
following is the XPath for the same

```
//*[preceding-sibling::comment()[contains(., 'comment 2')]][following-sibling::comment()[contains(., 'end content')]]
```

I am using HTML Agility Pack with below code:

```
var nodes = document.SelectNodes("//*[preceding-sibling::comment()[contains(., 'comment 1')]][following-sibling::comment()[contains(., 'InstanceEndEditable')]]");

string allHtml = nodes[0].OuterHtml;
```

If I change "comment 1" to "comment 2" in above code then it is not giving any result.

Comment: Note that the XPath in your HTML Agility Pack sample code contains an extra constraint (`[contains(., 'InstanceEndEditable')]]`) that you may have intended to edit out -- it does not match your example.

Comment: I rolled back your change of the source code because it completely changes the original question when you rearrange the source in that manner.  Feel free to ask a new question after finishing here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add a predicate that states that you want the *first* preceding comment and the *first* following comment.**

So, for example, to get the contents between the comments that starts with "comment 1":

```
//*[preceding-sibling::comment()[1][contains(., 'comment 1')]]
   [following-sibling::comment()[1][contains(., 'end content')]]
```

Similarly, to get the contents between the comments that starts with "comment 2":

```
//*[preceding-sibling::comment()[1][contains(., 'comment 2')]]
   [following-sibling::comment()[1][contains(., 'end content')]]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have updated the html in question now. Is it due to incorrect placing of "end comment" tag in 2nd time.

Comment: Woa, my answer worked for the original sample source you provided.  Please first confirm that.  Separately, your new change, where you move the comments to no longer be siblings, is substantive and really should constitute a new question.

Comment: thanks for reply, i have updated incorrect html in original question itself. Yes, I think your answer did helped me.

Comment: Note that you cannot use XPath to get the stuff between your comment markers if the comment markers delimit non-well-formed XML.