# XPath selecting text between comments

Tags: xpath

I have this HTML

```
<p>
<!-- templateDebugMode: start template: articleLists/indexHeadline.html -->
<!-- templateDebugMode: start template: articleLists/indexHeadline.html - templateCell: articleRow -->
December 18th 2017 : <a href="https://www.example.org/news/1195.shtml">News item 1</a><br>
<!-- /templateDebugMode: end template: articleLists/indexHeadline.html - templateCell: articleRow -->
<!-- templateDebugMode: start template: articleLists/indexHeadline.html - templateCell: articleRow -->
December 18th 2017 : <a href="https://www.example.org/news/1194.shtml">News item 2</a><br>
<!-- /templateDebugMode: end template: articleLists/indexHeadline.html - templateCell: articleRow -->
<!-- templateDebugMode: start template: articleLists/indexHeadline.html - templateCell: articleRow -->
November 29th 2017 : <a href="https://www.example.org/news/1191.shtml">News item 3</a><br>
<!-- /templateDebugMode: end template: articleLists/indexHeadline.html - templateCell: articleRow -->
<!-- /templateDebugMode: end template: articleLists/indexHeadline.html -->
</p>
```

I tried splitting on the `<br>` but using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404345/xpath-selecting-between-comments-multiple-times) found the comments to be reliable:

```
//*[preceding-sibling::comment()[1][contains(., 'start template: articleLists/indexHeadline.html')]]
   [following-sibling::comment()[1][contains(., 'end template: articleLists/indexHeadline.html')]]
```

This gets me the links (which I can get with a simpler expression) but not the date (text) preceding it. How can I extract this too for each entry? The data I'm looking to collect for each news item is:

- Date
- Link
- Link text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get required output with below XPath expressions

```
//p/text()[string-length(.)>0] # for date
//p/a/@href # for link
//p/a/text() # for link text
```

If you still want to use those comments in XPath:

```
//p/text()[preceding-sibling::comment()[1][contains(., 'start template: articleLists/indexHeadline.html')]]
          [following-sibling::comment()[1][contains(., 'end template: articleLists/indexHeadline.html')]]  # for date

//p/a[preceding-sibling::comment()[1][contains(., 'start template: articleLists/indexHeadline.html')]]
     [following-sibling::comment()[1][contains(., 'end template: articleLists/indexHeadline.html')]]/@href  # for links

//p/a[preceding-sibling::comment()[1][contains(., 'start template: articleLists/indexHeadline.html')]]
     [following-sibling::comment()[1][contains(., 'end template: articleLists/indexHeadline.html')]]/text()  # for link text
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked a treat. I modified the one for date to `//p/text()[normalize-space()][string-length(.)>0]` which got rid of some - but not all - of the whitespace. The <br> tag interfering?

Comment: I see no white-spaces. Maybe real HTML differs from provided? Try `//p/normalize-space()`

Comment: You're right sorry - I reformatted the HTML while indenting it for StackOverflow